# How to use computed field in syncfusion vue js data grid

Tags: vue.js, syncfusion

How can i use computed value in syncfusion vue js data grid ?

For example

Suppose i have 5 column as QUANTITY, MRP, DISCOUNT, DISCOUNTED PRICE, TOTAL.
I want to calculate DISCOUNTED PRICE from given values MRP and DISCOUNT.
And also want to calculate TOTAL from given value QUANTITY and DISCOUNTED PRICE.

How can i achieve this in syncfusion vue js databgrid? 
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html
You can read about default vue computed values, and add `v-bind:value='computedProperty'` to cell where you need calculation. If you give a sandbox with your code, I will try to help you more.

Comment: I know about computed property but There is no bind:value property in syncfusion vue js grid table. And even i don’t know how to pass data from e-column to function to calculate value.

Answer (score 0):

We understand on the initial page load you like to calculate the Total and Discount price based on the other three field values. Based on your query we have prepared a sample and achieved your requirement by using `queryCellInfo` event.

```
var templateGrid = Vue.component('ShowerTemplateList', { 
        template: ` 
                <ejs-grid ref='grid' id='grid' :dataSource="data" :columns='columns' 
                    :editSettings='editSettings' :toolbar='toolbar' :queryCellInfo='queryCellInfo' :actionComplete='actionComplete'> 
                </ejs-grid> 
            `, 
        `data: function () { 
            return { 
                data: new ej.data.DataManager({ 
                    url: "/Home/UrlDatasourceone", 
                    updateUrl: "Home/Updateone", 
                    insertUrl: "Home/Insertone", 
                    removeUrl: "Home/Removeone", 
                    adaptor: new ejs.data.UrlAdaptor() 
                }), 
                columns: [ 
                    { field: 'OrderID', headerText: 'ID', isPrimaryKey: true, width: 100 }, 
                    { field: 'Quantity', headerText: 'Quantity', width: 100 }, 
                    { field: 'MRP', headerText: 'MRP', width: 100 }, 
                    { field: 'Discount', headerText: 'Discount', width: 100 }, 
                    { field: 'Discountprice', headerText: 'Discount price', width: 100 }, 
                    { field: 'Total', headerText: 'Total', width: 100 } 
                ], 
                editSettings: { 
                    allowEditing: true, 
                    allowAdding: true, 
                    allowDeleting: true, 
                    mode: "Normal" 
                }, 
                toolbar: ["Add", "Edit", "Delete", "Update", "Cancel"] 
            } 
        }, 
        methods: { 
            actionComplete: function (args) { 
                if (args.requestType === "beginEdit") { 
                    var grid = document.getElementsByClassName("e-grid")[0] 
                        .ej2_instances[0]; 
                    grid.editModule.formObj.element[1].addEventListener("keyup", function ( 
                        e 
                    ) { 
                       var grid = document.getElementsByClassName("e-grid")[0] 
                            .ej2_instances[0]; 
                        var Totalquantity = +e.target.value; 
                        var GivenMrp = +grid.editModule.formObj.element[2].value; 
                        var Discount = +grid.editModule.formObj.element[3].value; 
                        var offerprice = (GivenMrp * Discount) / 100; 
                        var Res = GivenMrp - offerprice; 
                        grid.editModule.formObj.element[5].value = Res * Totalquantity; 
                    }); 
                    grid.editModule.formObj.element[2].addEventListener("keyup", function ( 
                        e 
                    ) { 
                        //For calculating price 
                        var grid = document.getElementsByClassName("e-grid")[0] 
                            .ej2_instances[0]; 
                        var GivenMrp = +e.target.value; 
                        var Totalquantity = grid.editModule.formObj.element[1].value; 
                        var Discount = +grid.editModule.formObj.element[3].value; 
                        var offerprice = (GivenMrp * Discount) / 100; 
                        var discountprice = GivenMrp - offerprice; 
                        grid.editModule.formObj.element[4].value = discountprice; 
                        grid.editModule.formObj.element[5].value = 
                            Totalquantity * discountprice; 
                    }); 
                    grid.editModule.formObj.element[3].addEventListener("keyup", function ( 
                        e 
                    ) { 
                       var grid = document.getElementsByClassName("e-grid")[0] 
                            .ej2_instances[0]; 
                        var discount = +e.target.value; 
                        var GivenMrp = +grid.editModule.formObj.element[2].value; 
                        var Totalquantity = grid.editModule.formObj.element[1].value; 
                        var offerprice = (GivenMrp * discount) / 100; 
                        var prc = GivenMrp - offerprice; 
                        grid.editModule.formObj.element[4].value = prc; 
                        grid.editModule.formObj.element[5].value = Totalquantity * prc; 
                    }); 
                } 
            }, 
            queryCellInfo: function (args) { 
                if (args.column.field === "Discountprice") {          //the querycellinfo triggers for every cell rendering 
                    var discount = (args.data.MRP * args.data.Discount) / 100; 
                    var discountprice = args.data.MRP - discount; 
                    args.data.Discountprice = discountprice;  //here we have calculated the discount price and updated the value to datasource 
                    args.cell.innerText = discountprice;     //here we have set the discount price to the cell value for UI changes 
                } 
                if (args.column.field === "Total") { 
                    var discountprice = (args.data.Discountprice * args.data.Quantity); 
                    args.data.Total = discountprice;          //here we have calculated the Total price and updated the value to datasource 
                    args.cell.innerText = discountprice;      //here we have set the Total price to the cell value for UI changes 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }); `
```

Sample:  https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/154221/ze/1542211673557847.zip

Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/api/grid/#querycellinfo